# 飛鵝山 final paragraph translation to English

Tags: translation

Could someone please translate this paragraph from [this essay](https://life.mingpao.com/chi/article?issue=20150925&nodeid=1508563418627) by 余光中.

> (第27段) 對着珠江口這一盤盤的青山，一灣灣的碧海，對着這一片南天的福地，我當風默許：無論我曾在何處，會在何處，這片心永遠縈迴在此地，在此刻踏着的這塊土上，愛新覺羅不要了，伊麗莎白保不了的這塊土上，正如它永遠向東，縈迴着一座島嶼，向北，縈迴着一片無窮的大地。

Is this OK?

(Paragraph 27) Against the Pearl River Estuary, the Qingshan Mountain, the blue sea of ​​Yiwan Bay, facing this piece of Nantian's blessed land, I am acquiesced: no matter where I used to be, my heart will forever return to this place, at this moment on the soil, Ai Xinjue Luo does not want to, **the soil that Elizabeth can't keep**, just as it always goes east, and returns to an island, heading north, and returning to an endless land.

Comment: You will not learn anything by having someone translate this text for you. At lease do some research yourself first.

Comment: user suggestion: asking about translation of a single  word (for which an (intentionally) erroneous translation may be proposed) will make question acceptable, answers will be allowed to cover entire text

Comment: @user6065 Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

珠江口盆地 Pearl River mouth basin
愛新覺羅 Aisin Gioro literally perhaps:
（section 27) Facing Pearl River mouth basin, these discs of green hills, these bays of green waters, facing this strip of southern fertile land, braving the wind I silently agree, no matter where I have been, where I will be, my thoughts will always hover at this place, the stretch of ground I am treading on at this instant, Aisin Gioro (the Qing dynasty) may be no more, (Queen) Elizabeth (II) may not be able to hold on to this piece of land, just as toward East they  always hover on some isle, toward North on some boundless land.

Comment: instead of "green waters" how about "emerald/blue sea"

Comment: 块 after demonstrative pronoun (指示代词) 这  and before 地 may function as classifier and therefore "stretch/piece" may be omitted in En (btw 这 is often used w/o CL)